# Will the Windows 8 Recovery USB "Reset" Option work on a blank HD?

Tags: windows-8, usb, system-recovery

Similar questions have been asked before at various times, but there is no clear answer on THIS question.

Neither do the instructions for the Windows 8 Recovery USB provide much of an answer.

Say I have a Lenovo notebook with Lenovo Windows 8 Pro OEM Version installed.

I use the utility to create a Windows 8 Recovery USB, which copies the recovery partition to USB.

Now i have a Windows 8 Recovery USB. Among the options with this USB is "Resetting your PC," which, according to Microsoft:

> ...reinstalls Windows but deletes your files, settings and applications – except for the applications that came with your PC. Restoring your PC is a way to undo recent system changes you’ve made.

What this does NOT tell me is whether "resetting my PC" works if Windows has been COMPLETELY ERASED from the SSD - a scenario in which "resetting" does not "delete your files, settings and applications" because the drive is completely blank.

For instance, if I wiped and repartitioned the SSD, installed Debian on it, and then, a year down the line, decided I wanted to wipe Debian and to return to the OEM Windows 8 Pro.

So the question is:

**If I wipe the drive completely, will I be able to reinstall Windows on my computer using the "reset your pc" option on my Windows 8 Recovery USB?**

Comment: No; because the required image file will be missing.  What do you hope from using it?

Comment: Is the required image file not copied when I create a Windows 8 Recovery USB?

I hope to have a way of restoring Windows 8 should I tire of using solo-boot Linux on the computer.

Comment: Create a System Image instead, this will do what you want....http://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-make-system-image-backup,26542.html

Comment: @breakingbits - No;  The image resides on the system disk where Windows is installed.

Comment: You should check the content of the USB. If there is a big (at least 2.x GB IIRC) `.wim` or `.esd` file then you should be able to use it to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you've ticked `Copy the recovery partition from the PC to the recovery drive` when you prepare the USB:

[image]

As the wizard mentioned, `If your PC came with a recovery partition, you can also copy it to the recovery drive so you can use it to refresh or reset your PC.`

The option is grayed out on non-OEM Windows, which does not have recovery image stored in the recovery partition by a vendor.

IIRC, the recovery image can get deleted by certain option in disk cleanup, and once it's deleted, the original recovery partition is shrunk and the space will go to the system partition. I am not sure if this (or when it's OEM Windows but somehow the vendor has not prepared a recovery image for you) will make the option grayed out.

However, in any case, you should be able to see a difference in the capacity requirement once you press `Next`. If NO recovery image is going to be copied to the USB, then the requirement should be only 256MB (and it's increased to 512MB in Windows 10):

[image]

Otherwise it should be much larger (3GB or more I think).

In Windows 10, the option is replaced with `Backup system files to recovery drive`:

[image]

which will make use of your `C:\Windows` to create an image when its ticked. (I never owned an OEM PC with Windows 10 pre-installed so I have no idea whether any of them comes with a vendor-prepared recovery image in the recovery partition and if so, whether the wizard will be aware of it.)

"Reset your PC" will wipe your drive anyway. You can choose whether to simply repartition/reformat the drive or do a full drive "zero-out" before that as well:
[image]

Don't mix it up with "Refresh your PC":
[image]

And make sure you do NOT go to `System Image Recovery` in `Advanced Options` when you boot the USB:
[image]
which is for restoring from system image created in the legacy `Backup and Restore (Windows 7)` in `Control Panel`